# bluetooth in background mode iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, background

I'm building an app that needs to run bluetooth in background mode. I configured the capabilities and added a string to the Info.plist file. When I built the app for the first time on my device (iPhone 6 with iOS 9.3.5) everything worked fine. I received the ".. would like to make data available to nearby bluetooth devices.. " dialogue, accepted it and my app worked in background. When I restarted the app background mode did not work any longer. I tried to remove the app from my iPhone and rebuilt it. The "would like to make data available" dialogue did not show even though the "receive remote notifications" dialogue does show after removing the app.
I tried to reset the Location & Privacy on my device and rebuilt the app. The dialogue was shown again and the app worked fine. I tried to rebuild it and it did not work anymore.

Can anyone help me so that my app can run in background without resetting Location & Privacy everytime?

Thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Some permissions are saved on your device, even if you remove the app and reinstall it, that's the case for notification permission.

You have some details on how to reset it here : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG42

I don't know if this is linked to your problem tho, you should check if the permission is already set in your device settings.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your tip. I've already had a look at that. Unfortunately it did not help. 
My problem is that the permissions seem to work fine at the first start of the app. When I restart it seems that the app won't get the permission to run in background. 
When I reset the Location & Privacy in the settings everything works until I restart the app again.